# SQL Server 2008 create trigger that set columns of a table to null after deleted row in another table

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

Suppose I have 2 tables:

```
T1                  T2
--------------      --------------------
id  name            ver lyr1    lyr2
--------------      --------------------
1   apple           1   1   1
2   banana          2   1   2
3   orange          3   3   3
4   peach           4   2   3
                    5   1   4
```

I want to update lyr1 and lyr2 values to null whenever a row is deleted in T1. So when id = 3 is deleted, result would be

```
T1                  T2
--------------      --------------------
id  name            ver  lyr1   lyr2
--------------      --------------------
1   apple           1    1      1
2   banana          2    1      2
4   peach           3    null   null
                    4    2      null
                    5    1      4
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigDelFruit on T1
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    UPDATE T2
    SET lyr1 = NULL, lyr2 = NULL
    FROM T2
    JOIN DELETED ON lyr1 = Deleted.id AND lyr2 = Deleted.id         
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--You cannot set particular columns set by this method. but you can achieve the same using "case when" statement.

CREATE TRIGGER trigDelFruit on T1
   AFTER DELETE
   AS
   BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   declare @id int;
   select @id=id from deleted;
   update T2 set
   lyr1=case when lyr1=@id then null else lyr1 end
   ,lyr2=case when lyr2=@id then null else lyr2 end;
   END

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Sorry for taking a while to get back.